# $\Sigma_3$-completeness of REG

Tags: computability

> Show the the following language is $\Sigma_3$-complete:
> $$ \mathrm{REG} = \{ \langle M \rangle \mid L(M) \text{ is regular}\}.  $$

Using the quantifier method I figured out that REG is in $\Sigma_3$, but how do I prove that it is $\Sigma_3$-hard?

Comment: The usual technique is a reduction from a problem already known to be $\Sigma_3$-hard. You can find some examples of such problems [here](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/kk3n/complearn/chapter11.pdf).

Comment: I'm assuming that $L(M)$ consists of all words on which $M$ halts.

Comment: Please don't delete questions after they have received an answer.  Part of our mission is to build up an archive of high-quality questions and answers that will be useful to others in the future, so deleting your question after it has been answered can be considered impolite to the person who took the time to write an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let COF consist of all Turing machines which halt on all but finitely many inputs. It is known that COF is $\Sigma_3$-complete, see [here](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/kk3n/complearn/chapter11.pdf) for example.

Given a machine $M$, whose inputs we identify with $\mathbb{N}$, we can construct another machine $M'$, defined as follows:

- If the input is not of the form $1^{n_1} 0 1^{n_2} 0 \cdots 0 1^{n_m}$ for some arbitrary $m$ and naturals $n_1 < \cdots < n_m$, then halt.
- Run $M$ in parallel on $n_1,\ldots,n_m$, and halt whenever one of the copies halts.

The *complement* of the language of this machine consists of all strings  of the form $1^{n_1} 0 1^{n_2} 0 \cdots 0 1^{n_m}$, where $n_1 < \cdots < n_m$ are non-halting inputs of $M$. Denote the complement by $L$.

If $M$ belongs to COF then $L$ is finite, and so regular. If $M$ doesn't belong to COF then we can use the Myhill–Nerode theorem to show that $L$ is not regular: indeed, if $n_i \neq n_j$ are two non-halting inputs of $M$, then $1^{n_i} 0$ and $1^{n_j} 0$ are inequivalent modulo $L$. This shows that $L(M) \in \mathrm{COF}$ iff $L(M') \in \mathrm{REG}$ (since regular languages are closed under complementation), and so REG is $\Sigma_3$-hard.

Comment: so, the step  "halt whenever one of the copies halts" mean that accept if M accepts and reject if M rejects?  In that case when M is in COF $\bar{L}$ is infinite and then $\bar{M}$ would accept infinite number of strings of type $1^{n_1}01^{n_2}0⋯01^{n_m}$ which is not regular.

Comment: If $M$ is in COF then there are only finitely many non-halting inputs, so $M'$ also has only finitely many non-halting inputs. Consequently, the language of inputs on which $M'$ halts is regular.

Comment: No it is not true i guess, If M is in COF then there are only finitely many non-halting inputs, but $M^{\prime}$ also has infinitely many non-halting inputs, because it also loops on inputs not of form $1^{n_1}01^{n_2}0...01^{n_m}$. So, $M^{\prime}$ will halt on inputs of  form $1^{n_1}01^{n_2}0...01^{n_m}$ and hence the language of  $M^{\prime}$ is not regular.

Comment: Right, it should probably halt if the input is malformed.